# How to flatten TimeStampSpec Column in json for druid?

Tags: json, database, configuration, apache-kafka, druid

I have a scenario where timestamp column is inside a json,like the below ones.

```
        {
          "version":"1.1",
          "header": {
            "name": "PlaceOrder",
            "schemaVersion": "1.2.0",
            "appName": "data-services-api",
            "appVersion": "1.0.0",
            "experimentId": "",
            "uuid": "27811b74-2333-494d-9623-00d36cbefb9b",
            "eventId": 35299,
            "timestamp": 1528351708570
         }
      }
```

Does anyone know how to specify this in the TimeStampSpec column of the config file?

```
        "timestampSpec": {
            "column": ???,
            "format": "millis"
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like below in your ingestion task config -

```
"$.header.timestamp"
```

I am assuming you are aware of using "flattenSpec" and "useFieldDiscovery" in config.